# Why do I get one object with a string when using ajax, when controller returns an array of objects?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I cannot seem to figure out why my $.get call returns one single object with a string containing my elements, when my controller returns a list of objects.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetInitialTags(int id)
{
    Model = new UnitDetailsModel(UnitClient.GetUnit(id));
    foreach (var tag in Model.ViewUnitContract.Tags)
    {
        Model.TagsSelected.Add(tag);
    }

    var result = Model.TagsSelected.Select(a => new
        {
            id = a.Id,
            text = a.Name
        });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This returns an array of two objects ([0], [1]). But, when I do my ajax call from view, like this:

```
var data = $.get('@Url.Action("GetInitialTags", "UnitDetails", new { id = Model.ViewUnitContract.Id })');
```

.. it returns one single object with a property `responseText` that contains my elements like this:

```
responseText: "[{"id":27,"text":"Norway"},{"id":28,"text":"Sweden"}]"
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It's returning an array of objects, which is the correct behaviour. What are you expecting as a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function doesn't *return* the data, it returns a `jqXHR` object, which is an extended version of the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object, which has multiple properties, including `responseText`.

You can get the deserialized data via the argument to the success callback:

```
$.get(
    '@Url.Action("GetInitialTags", "UnitDetails", new { id = Model.ViewUnitContract.Id })',
    function(data) {
    // Use `data` here
});
```

...or the argument to the `done` function on the returned `jqXHR` object, which is also a `Promise`.

```
$.get(
    '@Url.Action("GetInitialTags", "UnitDetails", new { id = Model.ViewUnitContract.Id })'
).done(function(data) {
    // Use `data` here
});
```

In both of the above, provided the server sent the response with the correct MIME type, `data` will be an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

> [{"id":27,"text":"Norway"},{"id":28,"text":"Sweden"}]

this is array of object...

anyways you can get the values inside get callback

```
 $.get('@Url.Action("GetInitialTags", "UnitDetails", new { id = Model.ViewUnitContract.Id })',function(data){
     var result=JSON.parse(data);
     alret(result[0].id);
})
```